# Mongodb unique array values combination index

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing, unique-constraint

I saw a lot of questions/answers about it but I couldn't find an answer which is helping me to move forward. Let say we have the following combination:

```
{"_id":"aaaaaa", "values":["ab", "bc"]}
{"_id":"bbbbbb", "values":["ma", "gu"]}
{"_id":"cccccc", "values":["em", "ix", "am", "23"]}
{"_id":"dddddd", "values":["em", "ix", "am"]}
{"_id":"eeeeee", "values":["gu", "ma"]}
```

Here I put strings (in my situation, each string are IDs from either NoSQL/SQL). As I understand, I cannot put an index that would make the array unique in term of combination (even worst, I wouldn't even be able to have a single value present in different documents in `values` if I put such indexation, again, as I understood)

The thing is that I have no idea in which direction to go...

**Some previous thoughts about possible approaches**

- I got, at first, the approach of having another table (Table 2) which contains document such as `{"document_id":"eeeeee", "value";"ma"}` so my problem is solved, otherwise, since I paginate/look/search over my documents, I need to have exponentials calls between the tables.
- The second solution I had was to sort this array and then, compares it with the data I want to insert but this can be **** by racing condition and then I would have a duplicate

Any idea? I am using Go as Backend

Comment: So in your example, since you have `{"_id":"aaaaaa", "values":["ab", "bc"]}`, would it be allowed to have `["bc", "ab"]`?

Comment: Nop that the thing, this would be a duplicate to me, I don't want it to be possible

Comment: How about concatenating them into a string like storing `ab|bc`, `ma|gu`, etc. You can then put a unique index on it, but you'd have to manually split them into arrays when you need them as arrays in your app, e.g. by using `values.split('|')` in Python

Comment: But then how do you manage push/pull of elements within the array? You have to extract, edit, then update. So if a racing condition append it crashes or at least it stops the current update execution :/

Comment: Can you at least have the array sorted? Will that be an issue?

Comment: To be honest I thought about it but can you push an element at a given position ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206092/discussion-between-emixam23-and-kevinadi).

Comment: @Emixam23 Any solution found? I have the same issue/problem.

Comment: Well @Marc I never found a solution using mongodb, i so started to use SQL like database where I could solve it (if i remember well)